Can your lawn benefit from going to seed? e.g. Can it overseed itself and grow thicker?
I did some research and I mostly read that it's a bad idea to let your lawn go to seed. However everyone who says that is someone who's selling grass seed. So I'd like to hear from an unbiased, scientific source. Can a lawn grow to seed and seed itself in any successful way?
Here's what I've read:
The seeds may not be viable, like trying to breed mules from other mules instead of a horse and a donkey.
The baby grass would not be anything like its parent, like planting a peach pit from a peach from a market.
Grass can repro more successfully by rooting than by seeding, and seeding just takes away energy that could have been used for rooting.
The reason I find this suspicious is because when you buy it you buy seeds in the first place, not clones or cuttings (unless it's sod). And you can see my strategy, let whatever grass has been successful in my yard thus far sow more.
I live in the North East USA. I don't know what breed was planted there in the first place (I only know my yard is shady and even though the bag said "shade" it is not doing very well and I'm trying to improve it.) Also my neighbors are on board with "no-mow May" and saving bees, etc. No one complains it's a foot high, so no trouble there. But when I accomplish what I want I'd like to mow it to look nice.

I think you get the question wrong. I think you should start: what do you want as lawn, and then you may ask this question. I think most of time we do not want lawn going to seed because it look ugly and you may get only one variety. OTOH on flowered lawn/fields, you really want such look and also seeds. So I would look the question on the other side: is it good going to seed if I want such kind of lawn (and in such region)
